# How to use the first four Ethernet ports on Arista 7050QX-32S?

Tags: arista

I'm trying to configure an Arista 7050QX-32S switch and basically the first 4 ports are missing on the switch.

This model is a full 40GbE switch and there's four 10GbE interfaces for convenience reasons. I've added two transceivers on Eth1 and Eth2, the switch was able to identify them in `sh logging` but I just can't access the interfaces:

```
ztp-default(config)#int eth 1
% Interface does not exist
ztp-default(config)#int eth 2
% Interface does not exist
```

Logs confirm that the port exists and they are identified:

```
Jan 20 20:16:40 ztp-default Fru: %FRU-6-TRANSCEIVER_INSERTED: A transceiver for interface Ethernet1 has been inserted. manufacturer: Arista Networks model: SFP-10G-CU0.5M part number SFP-10G-CU0.5M rev n/a serial number ARR200908026
Jan 20 20:17:05 ztp-default Fru: %FRU-6-TRANSCEIVER_INSERTED: A transceiver for interface Ethernet2 has been inserted. manufacturer: Arista Networks model: SFP-10G-CU0.5M part number SFP-10G-CU0.5M rev n/a serial number ARR200908036
```

I'm probably missing something, so the question is: how to enable or use those first four ports?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's documented here: [Arista 7050XSeries: Q&A](https://www.arista.com/assets/data/pdf/Whitepapers/7050X_Q_A.pdf) on page 7, the command you're looking for is:

```
hardware port-group 1 select Et1-4
```

Comment: Note that these four 10G ports use the same internal lanes as the 40G port 5, so you can only use either ports 1–4 or port 5. If you use the above command, interface Et5/1-4 will vanish.

Comment: Good point, I forgot to mention that!